# Embedding Cordova webview on Android (Windows 7 development environment)

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have followed the [these instructions](http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/installing-android-4-2-sdk-and-phonegap-2-4-0-on-windows-7/) to setup `Android 4.4 SDK`, `Eclipse` and `Cordova 3.5` on my `Windows 7` PC. The only point that deviated from these instructions is that I did not download `Phonegap` from a zip file, rather I installed it using:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

as per [these instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). Everything installed fine and I was able to create a Hello World app with `Cordova` and launch it on my `Android` device. So far, so good. :)

Now, however, I am needing to go a step further and need to get `Cordova` embedded in my own `webview` using the `CordovaWebView`. I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html) but I really am not understanding the steps outlined there. For example, on step 1 (yes, I am stuck on step 1!), it says:

```
 Use bin/create to fetch the commons-codec-1.6.jar
```

What is the "create" command? Is it a `Java` tool? What is the exact command that I would have to type in to do the fetch and will it work on `Windows`?

The next step says:

```
cd into /framework and run ant jar
```

Ok. I have got `Apache-ant-1.9.4` on my PC and got a path to it setup in my `Windows` `Path` environment variable, but where is the "framework" directory that I need to navigate to??

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand these instructions so that I can get this setup in my `Windows` environment.

Comment: Take a look a latest docs http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews

Comment: @Manjesh V Thanks for the link to the latest docs. I will try follow the steps outlined there.