# Embed CordovaWebView inside a larger application (Cordova version 5.2.0)

Tags: android, cordova

We have an `Android` application that is based on `Cordova 3.5`. The application does not make use of the `CordovaActivity`, rather it works by creating a `CordovaWebView` and embedding it inside the application. When I was initially building this application I was struggling to get the `CordovaWebView` instantiated and initialized in the application and I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897141/embedding-cordova-webview-on-android-windows-7-development-environment) asking for help. I was given [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews) to instructions on getting this setup. I followed the instructions and got the application working, although I did need to deviate from the instructions given because in our case the javascripts must be loaded from a remote server and not from the Android project's /assets/www folder.

Here is how I implemented our main activity for `Cordova 3.5`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MobileForms extends FragmentActivity implements CordovaInterface, RetryDialogListener, EditServerDialogListener
{
   protected FrameLayout webViewPlaceholder;
   protected MobileformsPreferences preferences;
   protected CordovaWebView cwv;
   protected CordovaPlugin activityResultCallback = null;
   protected boolean activityResultKeepRunning;
   protected final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        preferences = new MobileformsPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initializeUI();
        org.apache.cordova.Config.init(this);
        navigateToMobileforms();
    }

    protected void initializeUI() {
        webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));
        // Initialize the WebView if necessary
        if (cwv == null)
        {
            // Create the webview
            cwv = new CordovaWebView(this);
            cwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            cwv.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            cwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            cwv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            cwv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            cwv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            cwv.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, cwv) {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { 
                   try {
                       view.stopLoading();
                   } catch (Exception e) {}
                   if (view.canGoBack()) {
                       view.goBack();
                   }
                   view.loadUrl("about:blank");
                   Toast.makeText(MobileForms.this, "Cannot connect. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                   Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3500); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
                                showRetryDialog();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }  
                   };
                   thread.start();
               }
           });
           cwv.setWebChromeClient(new CordovaChromeClient(this, cwv) {});
           // Application cache
           cwv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
           cwv.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());  //"/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
           cwv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
           cwv.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*20);
           cwv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
       }
       // Attach the WebView to its placeholder
       webViewPlaceholder.addView(cwv);
   }

   protected void navigateToMobileforms() {
       String serverName = preferences.getServerName();
       if (serverName != null) {
           cwv.loadUrl(buildUrl(serverName));
       }
       else {
           showServerEditDialog();
       }
   }

   protected String buildUrl(String serverText) {
       return "http://"+serverText+"/path/to/index.php";
   }

   protected void showRetryDialog()
   {
       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
       RetryDialogFragment retryDialog = new RetryDialogFragment();
       retryDialog.show(fm, "retry_dialog");
   }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
   {
       // Remove the WebView from the old placeholder
       if (cwv != null) {
           webViewPlaceholder.removeView(cwv);
       }
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       // Load the layout resource for the new configuration
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       // Reinitialize the UI
       initializeUI();
   }

   @Override
   public Activity getActivity() {
      return this;
   } 


   /**
    * Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished.   When this activity exits,
    * your onActivityResult() method is called.
    *
    * @param command           The command object
    * @param intent            The intent to start
    * @param requestCode       The request code that is passed to callback to identify the activity
    */
    public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
       this.activityResultCallback = command;
       // Start activity
       super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    } 

    @Override
    /**
     * Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     *
     * @param requestCode       The request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(),
     *                          allowing you to identify who this result came from.
     * @param resultCode        The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
     * @param data              An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
     */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
       return threadPool;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSettings() {
        MobileForms.this.showServerEditDialog();
    }

    ... Code snipped ...

}
```

Please take note that I am only showing the code relevant to the `Cordova` implementation here.

Now the problem is that we are needing to take this code to the latest version of `Cordova` (version 5.2.0) and I am struggling to get this code converted to the latest version because it seems that a lot of restructuring of the `Cordova` code has taken place since version 3.5.0. For example, this line now no longer works:

```
cwv = new CordovaWebView(this);
```

because `CordovaWebView` is now an interface and not a class.

I have seen the [updated instructions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html) for implementing `Cordova` as a webview inside a larger app, but I am also struggling to get my mind around all of the classes and interfaces that are now in `Cordova` and how they all fit together. For example, `CordovaWebView`, `CordovaWebViewImpl`, `SystemWebView`, `CordovaWebViewEngine`, `SystemWebViewEngine`.

I would appreciate any help that can be offered in explaining how the different classes fit together and/or in porting the code that I copied above to `Cordova 5.2.0`.

Comment: try with the latest tutorial on the phonegap site http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/android/

Answer (score 1):

`CordovaWebView` is not a View anymore. You have to instantiante a `CordovaWebViewImpl` which holds the view, then call `getView()` on it to retrieve the view.

Here is the `CordovaView` which is a view that embeds the `CordovaWebViewImpl`. You can use it in place of the old `CordovaWebView`.

```
public class CordovaView extends FrameLayout {

    private CordovaWebViewEngine cordovaEngine;
    private CordovaWebView cordovaWebView;

    public CordovaView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ConfigXmlParser parser = new ConfigXmlParser();
        parser.parse(context);
        CordovaPreferences preferences = parser.getPreferences();
        ArrayList<PluginEntry> pluginEntries = parser.getPluginEntries();

        cordovaEngine = CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(context, preferences);
        cordovaWebView = new CordovaWebViewImpl(cordovaEngine);
        cordovaWebView.init(new CordovaContext(context), pluginEntries, preferences);
        View webView = cordovaWebView.getView();
        addView(webView);
    }

    public WebView getWebView() {
        View view = cordovaWebView.getView();
        if (!(view instanceof WebView))
            throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected view type");
        return (WebView)view;
    }

    public void setInitialScale(int scale) {
        getWebView().setInitialScale(scale);
    }

    private class CordovaContext implements CordovaInterface {

        private final Activity activity;
        private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        public CordovaContext(Context context) {
            if (!(context instanceof Activity))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must be an Activity");
            activity = (Activity)context;
        }

        @Override
        public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
        }

        @Override
        public Activity getActivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        @Override
        public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
            return threadPool;
        }

        @Override
        public void requestPermission(CordovaPlugin plugin, int requestCode, String permission) {
        }

        @Override
        public void requestPermissions(CordovaPlugin plugin, int requestCode, String[] permissions) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```